I'm trying to click on specific text using Selenium VBA in Excel; however, i'm unable to find the right xpath for it
I have this section of code:
bot.SwitchToNextWindow 'activates newly opened tab
bot.Wait (2000)

bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='IMECall']").Click`

Here is what the inspect code looks like:

However the macro errors saying no such element error:

Element not found for xpath=//div[text()='IMECall']

I'm admittedly new to this and hoping I'm just missing something obvious, but I've tried and read a lot and no luck. Any advice is appreciated.
I tried to use the code above and expected it to click on the part of the page that includes the text IMECall. What actually happened was an error saying element not found.

you might check to verify that the "next window" is what you expect, by taking a screenshot as bot.takescreenshot after your switch statement.  Also you are looking for exact text, if there is more text in that tag it won't match.

I'd suggest a few steps:

try running the same step after a few seconds (sometimes 2s is not enough to element to load)
check if you are interacting with the correct window/tab
verify if there are no "spaces" in the text
try using contain:
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[contains(text(), 'IMECall')]").Click
check for iframes (I had many problems with that when I was learning to use selenium with vba)
check if there is a tag "iframe" in devtools. if the element is inside a frame:

bot.SwitchToFrame bot.FindElementByTag("iframe")
bot.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='IMECall']").Click
bot.SwitchToDefaultContent ' Return to the main page
there are other steps, but those would be my first guesses
